# What is the easiest way to convert a PKCS8 formatted EC Key string into a JWK using ECSDA?

Tags: javascript, openssl, ecdsa, jwk, pkcs#8

I don't care if it is the OpenSSL, Python or other ways.

The reason why I want to convert from PKCS8 string (with Elliptic Curve key) to JSON Web Key (JWK), so I can see the claims like `kid`, etc

I've tried using the [eckles library](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/eckles.js/).

```
var Eckles = require('eckles');
var pem = require('fs')
  .readFileSync('./node_modles/eckles/fixtures/privkey-ec-p256.sec1.pem', 'ascii');

Eckles.import({ pem: pem }).then(function (jwk) {
  console.log(jwk);
});
```

but the output only returns the kty, crv, d, x, y .. but not the `kid` claims.

Comment: The [*kid*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517#section-4.5) is JWK specific, the [PKCS#8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208#section-5) format does not contain a *kid*, which is why none is exported.

Comment: Incidentally, the conversion PEM->JWK is also possible with the crypto module of NodesJS: `crypto.createPrivateKey(<your PEM key>).export({format: 'jwk'})`.